# Moving presta to different location

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, prestashop

I moved my shop from `exampledomain.com/prestashop` to `differentdomain.com`. Now if I go to `differentdomain.com`, the server provider tells me that I have to upload files into `public_html`, but if I type `differentdomain.com/index.php` everything works fine. I tried to modify the `shop_url` values in database, but this did not seem to have any effect. How can I make the shop appear when I go to `differentdomain.com`?

Here is my .htaccess:

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

Comment: Wait... what ? Sorry but i don't get it. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: There is something wrong because I have to add /index.php to my domain adress. In other case It's doesn't work (I think It's because .httacces)

Comment: Please update your question with your htaccess code. Also, i suspect a missing automatic directory index. If you're under Apache, you can add `DirectoryIndex index.php` to your htaccess

Comment: I've also found the reason of this bug. I was have index.html and index.php in parent directory.